# How to get API data in child component with props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, react-props

I am trying to call API data only once that's why I call API in home.js file with `componentdidmount` in class component and I want to render this data in many child components with functional components. When I call API in every each child component, it works but when I try to call with props coming only empty array by `console.log`. Please help.

```js
import React from 'react'
import '../styles/home.css'

import axios from 'axios';

import Teaser from './Teaser'
import Second from './Second'
import Opening from './Opening'
import Menu from './Menu'


export default class Home extends React.Component {
    state = {
      posts: []
    }
  
    componentDidMount() {
      
        axios.get("https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=id,caption,media_url,permalink,username&access_token=IGQ")
        .then(res => {
          const posts = res.data.data;
          this.setState({ posts });
      
        })
    }
   
 
 

  render() {
    return (
      <>
       
       <Teaser/>
      
       <Second/>
       
       <Opening/>
    
      <Menu posts={this.state.posts}/>
         
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

```js
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';

function Menu(props) {

    const {posts} = props.posts;
    console.log(props);


    return (
        <>
        {posts.map(
          (post) =>
            post.caption.includes('#apegustosa_menu') &&
            post.children.data.map((x) => (
              <div className="menu_item" key={x.id}>
                <img className="menu_img" src={x.media_url} alt="image" />
              </div>
            )),
        )}
      </>

    )
}

export default Menu
```

Comment: Is this a mistake in your typing when posting this question?  `const {posts} = props.posts;`

Comment: no i write it in this way ? is it the problem ?

Comment: Yes, that syntax is only for object. What you're trying to do is getting value of key `posts` in `props.posts` array. So what you will get for posts is `undefined`, I'm surprised that it's not throwing you an error at line `posts.map` since you cannot read `map` of `undefined`. I think if you just change that line to `const {posts} = props` that should work.

Comment: okay i understand.Now i have an array with data but do not render in html ? Maybe i still have a mistake in home.js how i define my props in the line where i write <Menu posts={this.state.posts}/>

Comment: have you tried `console.log` the `res.data.data`?

Comment: i defined now beginn of map with {posts && posts.map(  by return still not working :(

Comment: yes i do get data with console.log res.data.data

Comment: any other idea ? @TungPham

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. When I tried, I can still see values in the menu component. Is it possible for you to reproduce it on codesandbox or any other online editor and share the link? I think there might be other factor contribute to your problem.